# Wordpress Shortcode in Theme, Trying to use Gallery

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, themes

We are using SuperSlidShow Plugin to display gallery of images in our post. However when I write shortcode [gallery] in my post/page images appear correctly, but can anyone guide me if I want to fix this [gallery] shortcode in the theme itself like `page.php/post.php` so that images will appear on all pages. We have images for every page/post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery option1="value1"]'); ?>
```

from [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_the_gallery_shortcode).

Comment: thanks tha helpled, even <?php do_shortcode('[gallery]'); ?> but the problem is, it does not add items in header... the header part (scripts and css entries) are empty.

Comment: not sure what you mean, exactly.  Do you mean that all of your wordpress header stuff is missing?  If so, perhaps a little code from you template file mught be in order.  So might knowing which version of WordPress you're running.

Aside from that it looks to me like all the css applying to the out-of-the box galleries is in the standard files, so I'm unclear what you believe is missing.

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode

Answer (score 0):

works in wp 3.0 beta